# ElasticSearch does not expunge deleted documents

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

When I run `curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices'` I get the following result :

`yellow open my_index 5 1 8702175 2498002    35gb    35gb`

This is how I understand it :

I have ~8.7M documents in this index.
I have done many updates and that's why I have many ( ~2.5M ) deleted documents.
The datas in this index take 35gb on the disk.

I don't understand why the column `2498002` does not decrease with time. 
These are older versions of documents. Should not ElasticSearch expunge them
regularly ?

I have tried `curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/_optimize'` but it didn't change anything.

ElasticSearch version : 1.4.5
Lucene version : 4.10.4

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify the [`only_expunge_deletes`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/indices-optimize.html#optimize-parameters) parameter which is false by default.

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/_optimize?only_expunge_deletes=true'
```

After running this, your deleted document count should decrease

Comment: I thought that the parameters were used to specify the task we wanted to run and by default all tasks were run by `_optimize`. Thanks for pointing out the `false` default value.

Comment: Yes, great. I thought i had accepted your response this morning. Many thanks again.

Comment: You're probably reindexing existing documents, hence the deleted document count that goes up. It's nothing terrible.